# Sort ArrayBuffer[A] in scala?

Tags: arrays, sorting, scala

I have an array in Scala with the class `ArrayBuffer[Actor]`, where `Actor` is a class that implements the `Ordered[Actor]` trait. How do I sort this array without coding it manually?

I know there is an object called `Sorting`, but it doesnt seem to work since `ArrayBuffer` doesn't implement/extend the right classes.

How do I sort `ArrayBuffer[A]` type arrays?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Scala 2.8, you could use the `sortWith` method of the `ArrayBuffer[T]` class, which is inherited from the `SeqLike` trait.

The following code snippet sorts an `ArrayBuffer[T]` object in ascending order:

```
def ascendingSort[T <% Ordered[T]](xs: ArrayBuffer[T]) = xs.sortWith(_ < _)
```

Note that this does not mutate the actual `ArrayBuffer`, but creates a new one with the elements in the right order.

If you are using Scala 2.7, you could use the `stableSort` method of the `Sorting` object. This takes the elements of the `ArrayBuffer` and produces an array of elements sorted in the right order (given by a closure as an argument, ascending as a default).

For example:

```
val a = new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]()
a += 5
a += 2
a += 3

scala.util.Sorting.stableSort(a)
```

The important question is what do you want to do with the `ArrayBuffer`. Usually, a `Buffer` is used internally in different algorithms in order to increase the performance of intermediate results. If you are using it for that, have a look at the ways of sorting the collection you want to return at the end of your algorithm. The `Sorting` object already provides a way of transforming an `ArrayBuffer` into a sorted `Array`.

From the scaladoc of the `Buffer` class:

> Buffers are used to create sequences of elements incrementally

As you are using it with `Actor`s, it might be used for some kind of actor queue - in which case, you might want to have a look at the `Queue` collection.

Hope it helps,

-- Flaviu Cipcigan

Comment: I was stupid, i didnt read the description right so I thought the sortWith(...) would mutate the ArrayBuffer since I found the class in the mutable package. 

Thanks a billion, also respect for the fast reply ;)

Answer (score 0):

Btw, the Actor class here is my own class used for "Actors" in a world created using my new game engine for scala ("Awesome Game Engine for Scala ~ AGES"), so it has nothing to do with the concurrency actor class. Also, implementations of lists in scala are a jungle, everything is either deprecated or implemented in a lot of different ways...ArrayBuffer works for my need (my need being a variable size array for containing actors).

Hope this clarifies :)